# Unknown provider: DashboardServiceProvider <- DashboardService <- DashboardController

Tags: angularjs, http, controller

even if I read a lot of solutions according my problem, still to have this Error.
This is my Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping( "/dashboard" )
public class DashboardController {

    @RequestMapping( value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public HttpEntity<String> dashboard() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy" );    
        return new HttpEntity<String>( "Today is " + sdf.format( new Date() ) );
    }

}
```

this is my index.jsp

```
<body ng-app="dashboard">

    <div ng-controller="DashboardController">
        <p>Nome: <input type="text" ng-model="nome"></p>
        <p>Cognome: <input type="text" ng-model="cognome"></p>
        <input type="button" value="LOGIN" ng-click="login()"/>
    </div>

    <jsp:include page="includes.jsp"></jsp:include>

    <div ng-show="value==1">
        {{data}}
    </div>
    <div ng-show="value==0">
        {{ResponseDetails}}
    </div>


</body>
```

this is my module

```
var Dashboard = angular.module( 'dashboard', ['DashboardService'] )
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            $routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {
                templateUrl: '/WEB-INF/pages/dashboard.jsp',
                controller: 'DashboardController'
            });
        }]);
```

my service

```
Dashboard.factory('DashboardService', function ($http) {

    return {
        dashboard: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
            $http.get("/dashboard")
                .success(
                    function (response) {
                        $scope.data = response;
                    }
                ).error(
                function (response) {
                    $scope.data = "ERROR!";
                }
            )
        }
    }
});
```

and finally my controller

```
angular.module("dashboard", [])
    .controller( 'DashboardController', function ($scope, DashboardService) {
        $scope.nome = "Daniele";
        $scope.cognome = "Comandini";

        var data = {
            nome: $scope.nome,
            cognome: $scope.cognome
        };

        $scope.value = 0;

        var login = function() {
            alert("LOGIN ON DASHBOARD");

            DashboardService.dashboard();
        };

        $scope.login = login;

    });
```

My JSP page must only send the request to the DashBoardcontroller, that it has the return the page dashboard.jsp with the current date.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the question: when I load the index.jsp, I see on console the follow error:

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/unpr?p0=DashboardServiceProvider%20%3C-%20DashboardService%20%3C-%20DashboardController

Answer (score 0):

You must not inject dependencies in your module. Dependencies like `service`, `factory` have to be injected in controllers. By the way, don't forget to inject `ngRoute`.

Module becomes:

```
var Dashboard = angular.module( 'dashboard', ['ngRoute'] )
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            $routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {
                templateUrl: '/WEB-INF/pages/dashboard.jsp',
                controller: 'DashboardController'
            });
        }]);
```

Your controller code is good, just one thing: if you want to use a code compiler like *Grunt*, *Gulp* or *Webpack*, don't forget to add your dependencies as strings:

```
angular.module('dashboard')
    .controller( 'DashboardController', ['$scope', 'DashboardService'], function ($scope, DashboardService) {
```

Comment: Now I have another error, Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error, and reading the link that it gave me, it speaks about from version 1.2.x the ng-route become a separated module that I have to import. I did it, I have a file includes.jsp in which I specify where are the angular.min.js and the angular-route.min.js. How can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. You have to inject ngRoute dependencies in your app. I'm editing my answer

Comment: Sorry, I have some more question. I already did it by myself the ngRoute injection, but now I receive this other error: Argument 'DashboardController' is not a function, got string.

Comment: I'd like to know if the service is correct, if the controller does not need any other injection... I think I'm so close to have the solution, but I still to go around it, and I don't want to mess my code. Can you help me one more time, please?

Comment: Concerning your last error, I don't know, you need to provide more informations about it.
I may be wrong, but service & ctrl seems good after that

Comment: This is what I receive in F12 mode with Google Chrome.https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=DashboardController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined

Comment: Well, that is all the code that I have... It's a very simple example because I'm new on angular and I want to understand it step by step. Is there any place where i can send you a zip with all my code?

Comment: You can post it on Plunkr and copy link here

Answer (score 0):

I copied your controller with the service injection

```
.controller( 'DashboardController', ['$scope', 'DashboardService'], function ($scope, DashboardService) {
```

but in the end I had to write this

```
Dashboard.controller( 'DashboardController', ['$scope', 'DashboardService' , function ($scope, DashboardService) {
        $scope.nome = "Daniele";
        $scope.cognome = "Comandini";

        var data = {
            nome: $scope.nome,
            cognome: $scope.cognome
        };

        $scope.value = 0;

        var login = function() {
            alert("LOGIN ON DASHBOARD");

            DashboardService.dashboard();
        };

        $scope.login = login;

    }]);
```

I mean I had to include the function into [], and not outside.